# Tauri Build Error unterminated character in import

Tags: rust, import, webview, tauri

Error:

```
error[E0762]: unterminated character literal
 --> src\main.rs:1:22
  |
1 | import { open } from '@tauri-apps/api/dialog';
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Error line:

```
import { open } from '@tauri-apps/api/dialog';
```

Project maked by npm on Vanilla javascript

I want to create file dialog. I tried to update rust and cargo(now 1.77)

Comment: That is a Rust file (`.rs`) and a Rust error message, but that is not Rust syntax. Did you mean to put it in some other `.js`, `.ts`, or `.tsx` file perhaps?

Comment: Thank you, i'll do this. I'm just bad in rust